# Creating a Folder

Tags: java, android, file, directory, creation

I am trying to create a folder call `"YouDown"` at the moment I don't care where the folder is located but at this time all I want to figure out is creating it. I found that my first issue was that `mkdir()` and `mkdirs()` were being ignored due to not knowing it was a Boolean value. I created the Boolean of `success` and now its not being ignored. Following this I created log.d of each step in detecting to creating to already existing. It registers that it `"Doesn't exist"` , `"Being Created"` then either `"Created"` or `"Creation Failed"`. It jumps to the `"Creation Failed"`. Everything I find now to help is just being repetitive to what I've been reading for the past few days. I am also looking into how I could apply this to a specific path way like the variable string I want it to be created inside the directories Music folder

// Lastest try

```
String Tag2 = "YouDown"

if (!dir.exists()) {
       Log.d(Tag2,"Doesnt Exist");
       boolean success = false;

       try{
           success = dir.mkdir();
           Log.d(Tag2,"Being Created");

       }
       catch(SecurityException se){
           //handle it
       }
       if(success) {
       Log.d(Tag2, "Created");
       } else{
           Log.d(Tag2, "Creation Failed");
    }
}
```

// Other Try

```
String path = "/sdcard/Music/Youdown"

if(new File(path).exists()){

Log.d(Tag2, "Exists");

} else {

Log.d(Tag2, "Being Created");
Boolean succes = new File(path).mkdir();

if(success){

  Log.d(Tag2, "Created"

 } else {

  Log.d(Tag2, "Failed"
}
```

Newest attempt

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path2);
    Boolean A = dir.mkdirs();

    if(A){
        Log.d(Tag2,"Created");
    }
    if(!A){
        Log.d(Tag2,"Failed");
    }
```

Comment: "at the moment I don't care where the folder is": you should care. You need to use a location where you are allowed to write.

Comment: How would I write the location then. I would prefer it to be in the music folder and I've come to this /sdcard/Music/YouDown

Answer (score 0):

Although Android has a hierarchical file system your app may read and write in certain places only. As a start I suggest using the method `getDir()` of `android.content.Context`. As the doc states:

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files created through a File object will only be accessible by your own application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of individual files.

If you want to access shared directories you need to call other methods, for example `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the directory for your app only, such that if ever your app gets deleted the folder gets deleted too, you can use `getFilesDir()`.

```
File internalDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
String path = "/Music/Youdown";       
// to create it you can call, new File(internalDir, path).mkdir();
```

Or alternatively if you want the external storage you would use the `Environment.getExternalStorage();` like below:

```
String path = "/Music/Youdown";       
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path );
 if (!f.exists()) {
     f.mkdirs();
 }
```

Comment: I like your alternative idea but I have an Error with the getExternalStorage.

Comment: there is no error now besides the difference I am using a boolean value. mkdirs is ignored if there is no value. I have updated the post

Comment: @MickeyT does your device have SDCARD?

Comment: I noticed now but I am going to remove the"/sdcard/ portion of it

Comment: the /sdcard has made no difference

Comment: @MickeyT add permission to write to external storage

Comment: @MickeyT have you tried using the getFilesDir from a context instead?